# Best way to read contents from a .json link

Tags: json, parsing, appcelerator-mobile

I've been given a link to a .json file, what is the best way to go about retrieving the contents and then parsing it?

Comment: refer following link.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824063/best-way-to-json-parsing-using-javascript) ..here explain very well..hope it will help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in Titanium mobile then...

1. Fetch the JSON data using [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)
2. Then transform the response to JSON object using [JSON.parse()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Global.JSON)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use this: [JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

and in PHP exists built-in functions for that: [JSON in PHP](http://us.php.net/json_encode)

And when you are using JavaScript you can fetch the data with a simple Ajax request.